# How to remove spaces from barcode in Zebra (ZPL) label?

Tags: strip, spaces, zebra-printers, removing-whitespace, zpl

I have a Canadian zip code that arrives with a space in the middle. There is no way to change the data, and it's fine for the human readable field. The barcode field, however, cannot have a space in it. Looking for a way to remove that pesky space from showing up in the barcode field.

In the past I've used ^TB (text block) to truncate human readable fields, but I think this isn't an option with a barcode. I've poured over the documentation and found nothing...

Here's my code currently:

```
^BY2,0.0
^FT0215,0526^BCN,0114,N,N,N,N
^F8^FV>:420*zip_code^FS
```

Anyone know a way out of this pickle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZPL is best described as a markup language, there are no string functions or anything to remove spaces.  The spaces must be removed before merging with the ZPL code.

Comment: Ah. Guessed that this might be a case, but wasn't quite ready to lay down the law in case there was a workaround. Good to have an experienced second opinion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
^FT0215,0526^BCN,0114,N,N,N,D
^FD(420)zip_code^FS
```

or for a bit more fun,

```
^FT0215,0526^BCN,0114,Y,N,N,D
^FD(420)zip_code^FS
```

This should work with `x.11.x` and later firmware.

I tried to get Zebra to implement UCC/EAN-128 back in 1997. Their reply was that UCC/EAN-128 and SSCC were one and the same thing...

Comment: Thanks! This looks useful, though from what I read in the docs it would be helpful mainly if there were an issue with the leading FNC1 char? It doesn't seem to remove the space from the data.

I'll hold onto that FNC1 info though, as I've run into that issue before! :-)